# Update Data Categories selection from knowledge article in salesforce

Tags: knowledge, servicecloud

I want to update data category selection from knowledge article's custom field.

[image]
I have written a process builder and calling apex from there. but it is not updating data category selection But in debug logs i can see insertion is done.
Below is the apex class:

```
@InvocableMethod
    public static void updatekMA1rticleType(List<Id> knowledgeid)
    {

        List<Knowledge__DataCategorySelection> kADCSLst = new List<Knowledge__DataCategorySelection>();
        List<Knowledge__kav> kArticle = [SELECT ID FROM Knowledge__kav  WHERE Id IN: knowledgeid];
       for(Knowledge__kav kak: kArticle)
        {
            Knowledge__DataCategorySelection kADCS = new Knowledge__DataCategorySelection();
            kADCS.ParentId = kak.Id;
            kADCS.DataCategoryGroupName = 'Geography';
            kADCS.DataCategoryName = 'India';
            kADCSLst.add(kADCS);
         }
          if(kADCSLst.size()>0)
            {

                insert(kADCSLst);
                system.debug('res**'+kADCSLst);

            }
     }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @santanuBoral
Can you help me on this?

Comment: If I run the code from Developer Console, it is perfectly inserting data category into my one of the published article

Comment: @Santanu Boral: 
Thanks for reply..it is working fine for me too but when same code is called from process builder then it is not working.. I checked the logs it is inserting data but i think it is getting rolled back..I have written process builder on Knowledge object(__kav)..

Comment: Is that correct version Id is getting passed to that method? can you post process picture?

Comment: @Santanu Boral:
I added the picture of process builder. I am passing the [knowledge__kav.id] to the method. In debug logsi can see data categories selection is getting inserted but it is getting rolled back for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I used @future annotation method called from @invocableMethod then it was working fine.

Comment: @ SFDC  Can you please share where the @Future should be used from the abouve code?